# date field missing when use date popup with date & time

Tags: 7, datetime

in my custom module, I have used the following code:

```
$form['event_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => 'Set Date & Time :',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-y H:i',
    '#default_value' => date('d-m-y H:i'),
    '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3',
    );
```

but after submitting it only show time field value. also work fine when only use date('d-m-y').

[image: screenshot]

Comment: What is in `$form_state['values']['event_date']` both in the validation and submit handlers?  The names in your two screenshots don't match up.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, I found it in `$form_state['input']`.

I am actually using this with Ajax. so In callback function you can get the form values from `$form_state` array. All form values are present in `$form_state['values']` and input type values are also can be found in `$form_state['input']`.

Comment: Could you please try to edit this answer so it would be usable for future readers?

Comment: Currently it is not understandable, please explain brief, we accept only quality Q&A.

Answer (score 0):

In my custom form, add your code:

```
function donation_form($form, &$form_state) {


$form['event_date'] = array(
    '#type' => 'date_popup',
    '#title' => 'Set Date & Time :',
    '#date_format' => 'd-m-y H:i',
    '#default_value' => date('d-m-y H:i'),
    '#date_year_range' => '-3:+3',
    );


  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#submit' => array('donation_ok'),

  );   

  return $form;
}
 function donation_ok($form, &$form_state) {     
   dpm($form['event_date']['#value']);
   dpm($form_state['values']['event_date']);
   dpm($form_state['input']['event_date']);
 }
```

[image]

you can use:

```
dpm($form['event_date']['#value']);
dpm($form_state['values']['event_date']);
dpm($form_state['input']['event_date']);
```

result:

[image: ![enter image description here]